# How to control the order of joined records in Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4. Sqlite3 DB (for development).

My model looks like this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :people, through: :memberships
  has_many :notes, as: :notable

  scope :with_active_members, -> { joins(people: [:role]).where(people: {active: true}).uniq }

end
```

And I use it like this:

```
@groups = Group.with_active_members.order("groups.position")
```

The join works perfectly well. But I want to order the people records alphabetically. To be very clear, I *don't* want to order the groups by their associated people. I want the groups to be ordered by their `position` field but I want the associated collections of people to be ordered alphabetically. Can this be done with the ORM?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can do this in the model:

```
has_many :people, ->{ order('first_name') }, through: :memberships
```

This works in some situations, but I'm not accepting it as the answer because what I really need is a way to set this in the controller, so that the order can be controlled dynamically.